# How do I build a Pebble.js project from the command line tools?

Tags: pebble-watch, pebble-sdk, cloudpebble

I created a new Pebble.js project in the CloudPebble editor, and I can successfully build it and push it to my watch from there. The problem arises when I try and build/install it from the command line, with the `pebble build` command returning this:

```
[ERROR   ] The Pebble project directory is using an outdated version of the SDK!
[ERROR   ] Try running `pebble convert-project` to update the project
```

And the `pebble convert-project` command returning:

```
[ERROR   ] Could not find usage of PBL_APP_INFO
```

Now I know for a fact that I have a working Pebble project here, and this is the exact code which the CloudPebble editor created; so how am I supposed to use the SDK then?

Answer (score 2):

To compile a Pebble.js project with the Pebble SDK on your computer you need to follow these steps:

1. Fork the official Pebble.js [repository from Github](https://github.com/pebble/pebblejs). This is a valid Pebble project
2. Replace the JS code in `src/js/app.js` with your code. If you have multiple files, you can add them in that folder too. You should not touch `main.js` or `loader.js`. Leave them here.
3. Compile the project just like you would compile any Pebble project (pebble build)

Hope this helps!

Comment: It's getting there, but it's failing currently and giving me `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_node'` when I try to build. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Looks like a problem with your appinfo.json file.Can you post a link to your project as a zip file here? Or send it to pebble developer support and we will look at it (devsupport at getpebble.com).

Comment: I'll send a link in to the code then, hopefully I'm just missing something obvious, but having done virtually nothing to the base project found on Github I'm not totally sure where the problem might lie.

Comment: Deeply sorry to revive this but I get:
Pebble.js is not part of the pebble SDK, and so the SDK can't build it.

How can I add pebblejs to the local pebble SDK?